# import export herokuapp data to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have an running on heroku which has data added via the rails admin panel.

I want to have that exact similar data locally on my machine.

With [this method](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) I am able to generate the latest dump of that heroku data.

How do I import this dump locally now?

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Note - I make an app/private directory and ignore it in git, but you can put the dump anywhere you like.  I use this sequence of commands to get production data to development.

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app your_app_name
curl -o private/latest.dump `heroku pg:backups public-url --app your_app_name`
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -d your_app_development private/latest.dump
```

Comment: umm I have this case now where I have got access to a heroku app. I want to get that data's latest dump.

If I run the above command, It'll generate the dump from the site for which I had access earlier. 

In short I now have access to two apps and I want second apps data dump

Answer (score 0):

Guess you're using `postgres` and locally you've the `postgres` installed. Run this command from command line with necessary details, such as hostname, databasename, file name to import the dump sql file.

```
psql -h hostname -d databasename -U username -f file.sql
```

// file.sql is the dump file you download from heroku